# How can one determine the origin of a given Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, dependencies

Given a local Maven repository, can one determine the remote repository that is the source of a particular dependency?  How?

Comment: Why do you need such information, for SNAPSHOTS?

Comment: For browsing the POM files in the source repository and seeing whether a repository contains all dependencies in a dependency group.  If, for some reason, Maven cannot find in a repository a dependency which is a  member of dependency group, but it finds all other dependencies in that group, will Maven retrieve the missing dependency from a different repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by @Eugene, the origin of a dependency isn't stored anywhere so the only way to find this after the fact (if you're not behind a corporate repository) would be to purge the dependencies of a given project and to re-resolve them. The following goal of the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) can do that:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=true
```

Note that [`reResolve`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#reResolve) is set to `true` by default, I just mentioned it for documentation purposes.

Comment: @Derek: Yes, it won't run any other phase or goal.

Comment: How can I tell Maven to suppress the messages for repositories in which it cannot find a dependency while displaying those where it finds a dependency?  (That is, display the hits, but not the misses sine the misses drown out and obscure the hits.)

Answer (score 1):

Maven don't store such information. However if you purge your local repository and run your project build you can see the actual repository url when artifact is downloaded during Maven build.

However if you are using Maven repository manager like Nexus you can search artifact by its id, version, etc and then see artifact source in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the dependency from your local repository and then see where it pulls from on your next build.

Comment: What Maven command can you use to just download dependencies, but otherwise not build the targets?